# Is there a way to hide optional fields while using autoforms in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I'm using autoforms to build a rather lengthy form. SOme fields are populated by default values and I do not wish for them to appear since the end user will mostly not be touching them unless there is a specific necessity. I went through the documentation for autoforms and the demo page, but nothing is clearely mentioned about how to have these fields hidden away and then shown upon clicking on 'Advanced' or something like that. A little advice on how to get this thing going will be useful.

Documentation sources:

http://autoform.meteorapp.com/

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=afquickfieldschema&oq=afquickfieldschema&aqs=chrome..69i57.3232j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=afquickfield+options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used simple collapsible s  to meet this specific requirement.